# Replacing Goose in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, goose

I've tryed to install Goose-extractor for my python/flask project but it gives the error message:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int "Unit tests have failed!")?
```

It seems that Goose doesn't support Python3, so what library can I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new fork of goose as goose3 that works with python3 
https://github.com/goose3/goose3

other than goose there are many other extractors you can look into for python such as html2text(though not as advanced -sufficient for simple extraction ) , Lassie, newspaper,textract .